# Creating docker image using maven

Tags: docker, maven-plugin

I am building a docker image using maven plugin com.spotify. its giving error when I execute below command:

```
mvn clean package docker:build
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.16.4:build (default-cli) on project xbs-docker: Execution default-cli of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.16.4:build failed: No  given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable, no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' or '//./pipe/docker_engine' and no external provider like Docker machine configured -> [Help 1]

When I set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375, its giving below error :

```
 Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.16.4:build (default-cli) on project <project_name>: Execution default-cli of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.16.4:build failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.16.4:build (default-cli) on project  <project_name>: Execution default-cli of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.16.4:build failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.16.4:build failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.DockerConnectionDetector.getCertPath(DockerConnectionDetector.java:108)
    at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.createDockerAccess(AbstractDockerMojo.java:277)
    at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Post complete exception

Comment: Please check updated post

Comment: Did you already saw this [issue](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/764)?

Comment: actually, i got this error in first attempt of build itself.

Comment: Can you please share your pom entries for the plugin?